# Suppress exception from Task.Delay()

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, async-await, cancellation-token

I have an async Task and a Task.Delay(time,token) inside that. I make an await call to that method from my main thread. Whenever the cancellation token is true, its breaks my main thread. I need to handle/avoid any exceptions from the Task.Delay(). Is there any possibility ?

Code snippet :

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await StartHealthMonitorAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

private async Task StartWorkAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var delaySpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(delaySpan, cancellationToken);
            await someTask.DoWorkAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: _"I need to handle/avoid any exceptions from the Task.Delay()"_ -- did you actually _try_ to handle the exception? I.e. put try/catch around the `await`? That's how you do it. If you can't get that to work, post a good [mcve] showing how you tried to do it, and explain what exactly happens instead of what you want.

Comment: I tried to handle with try/catch. but not getting the exception when passing cancellation token as true.

Comment: @JyothisTS, Can you show how you tried to handle it with try/catch?

Comment: `Task.Delay` will throw `OperationCanceledException` for cancelling the task. How this can break your main thread?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to handle/avoid any exceptions from the Task.Delay(). Is there any possibility?

Yes. Use `catch`:

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await StartWorkAsync(cancellationToken);
}

private async Task StartWorkAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var delaySpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
  try
  {
    while (true)
    {
      await Task.Delay(delaySpan, cancellationToken);
      await someTask.DoWorkAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
  }
}
```

I also removed the extra check for `IsCancellationRequested`, since it is not necessary.

Comment: I think `Task.Delay` throws `TaskCancelledException` not `OperationCanceledException`... UPDATE: nevermind, one inherits another